# After successful fetch request.. Unable to transform the data to ViewModel Published var using combine subscriber .sink

Tags: networking, swiftui, viewmodel, fetch-api

CURRENT SITUATION: Okay so the example code on here works  but if i do this same code 4x more times to make 4 rows under each other in my larger project.. it does not work. Maybe it is too much calls for the API at the same time because i call them all at the same time.. please let me know!

- I am fetching data from free API to a @published var.. successfully
- then in ViewModel I subscribe to the @published var and try to .sink into my ViewModel @published var... and it doesn't work! I think its bcs of the mistakes in timings when I call these 2 funcs
- I am using the OMDb free API and it worked perfectly up until now

Shorter example code to display the problem:

DataManager with the @published var and fetch func

```
class DataManager {
    
    static let instance = DataManager()
    
    let apiKey: String = "c2e5cb16"
    
    @Published var fetchedSPIDERMAN: SearchModel = SearchModel(search: nil, totalResults: nil, response: nil)
    var cancelFetchAllSelections = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private init() {
        fetchSpiderman()
    }
    
    func fetchSpiderman() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=\(apiKey)&s=spider") else { return print("MY ERROR: BAD URL") }
        
        NetworkingManager.download(url: url)
            .decode(type: SearchModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .sink(receiveCompletion: NetworkingManager.handleCompletion,
                  receiveValue: { [weak self] (moviesDownloaded) in
                self?.fetchedSPIDERMAN = moviesDownloaded
                print("fetchedSPIDER")
            })
            .store(in: &cancelFetchAllSelections)
    }
}
```

ViewModel with the other @published var and func .sink

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let dataService = DataManager.instance
    
    @Published var selectionForSpiderman: [MovieModel] = []
    @Published var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    
    init() {
    }
    
    func sinkToSelectionForSpiderman(){
        dataService.$fetchedSPIDERMAN
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] (fetchedMovieModel) in
                if let unwrappedFetchedMovieModel = fetchedMovieModel.search {
                    self?.selectionForSpiderman = unwrappedFetchedMovieModel
                }else {
                    print("MY ERROR: CANT SINK SPIDERMAN")
                }
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

In console it shows the  print("MY ERROR: CANT SINK SPIDERMAN")

HomeView with .onAppear calling the vm.sinkToSelectionSpiderman()

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    @StateObject var vm: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    
    let randomUrl: String = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/525982128/cs/fotografie/agresivita-koček.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=y632ynYYyc3wS5FuPBgnyXeBNBC7JmjQNwz5Vl_PvI8="
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(vm.selectionForSpiderman) { selection in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: selection.poster ?? randomUrl)) { returnedImage in
                            switch returnedImage {
                            case .empty:
                                ProgressView()
                            case .success (let image):
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 200,
                                           height: 120,
                                           alignment: .leading)
                                    .background(Color.red)
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .cornerRadius(10)
                                    .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                            case .failure (_):
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            default:
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Text(selection.title ?? "NA")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded, weight: .medium))
                            .padding(.leading, 12)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: 210)
                }
                .accentColor(Color.white)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            vm.sinkToSelectionForSpiderman()
        }
    }
}
```

My models are normally working with other Fetch funcs.

The main question is:
I am pretty sure I need to call the .sink func after the Fetch func... but idk if the .onAppear block of code executes before the Fetch func is finished and had time to sent the data to the subscriber .sink func?

Interesting fact:
Once it actually showed the data in the scrollView in the Canvas :DD unfortunately just once and never again.. maybe the API is slow

I have tried to look up how the timings work in SwiftUI and when to call which function but it is too specific and I didn't find an answer to it. If you know any resources where I can study this kind of stuff, please let me know!! :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please post a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need 2 class for dataManager and ViewModel. It can be made simpler :

```
// Data structures defined from the json data
struct MovieModel: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { // Identifiable for ForEach
        imdbID
    }
    let title: String
    let year: String?
    let imdbID: String
    let type: String?
    let poster: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title = "Title"
        case year = "Year"
        case imdbID = "imdbID"
        case type = "Type"
        case poster = "Poster"
    }
}

struct SearchModel: Codable {
    var search: [MovieModel] = []
    var totalResults: String = "0"
    var response: String = "False"
    var responseOK: Bool {
        response == "True"
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case search = "Search"
        case totalResults = "totalResults"
        case response = "Response"
    }
}

// The data manager handle the data receiving and put these in its published var movies
class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = DataManager()
    
    let apiKey: String = "c2e5cb16"
    @Published var movies: [MovieModel] = []
    var cancelFetchAllSelections = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private init() {
        // No need to call fetch here as it is done in onAppear
    }
    
    func fetchSpiderman() {
        // https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=c2e5cb16&s=spider
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=\(apiKey)&s=spider") else { return print("MY ERROR: BAD URL") }
        print("start request on \(url.absoluteString)")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        // URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher is handy to retrieve data from network 
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .map(\.data) // Publish the received data
            .decode(type: SearchModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder()) // decode dara
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // on main queue to refresh display
            .map({ searchModel in
                if searchModel.responseOK {
                    print("Response ok : \(searchModel.totalResults) results")
                    return searchModel.search
                } else {
                    print("Response error")
                    return []
                }
            }) // Return the received movies
            .catch() {error -> Just<[MovieModel]> in
                print("Exception : \(error)")
                return Just(self.movies)
            }
            .assign(to: &$movies) // save into items
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    // This is the model
    @StateObject var dataManager = DataManager.instance
    
    // Shortcut to get movies from the model
    var movies: [MovieModel] {
        dataManager.movies
    }
    
    let randomUrl: String = "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/525982128/cs/fotografie/agresivita-koček.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=y632ynYYyc3wS5FuPBgnyXeBNBC7JmjQNwz5Vl_PvI8="
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                // Loop on the movies
                ForEach(movies) { selection in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: selection.poster ?? randomUrl)) { returnedImage in
                            switch returnedImage {
                                case .empty:
                                    ProgressView()
                                case .success (let image):
                                    image
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 200,
                                               height: 120,
                                               alignment: .leading)
                                        .background(Color.red)
                                        .scaledToFill()
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                        .shadow(color: Color.white.opacity(0.2), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                                case .failure (_):
                                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                default:
                                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Text(selection.title)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded, weight: .medium))
                            .padding(.leading, 12)
                    }.frame(maxWidth: 210)
                }
                .accentColor(Color.white)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // starting the fetch
            dataManager.fetchSpiderman()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!  After 3 days of trying to figure out why is my app not working... the problem was just to put the .onAppear on different part of the code LMAO

Comment: Thank u so much for this suggestion!!! Your solution is much more clean and efficient. I hope one day I can write efficient code like u 

Comment: If you want to learn more read [this article](https://www.donnywals.com/implementing-an-infinite-scrolling-list-with-swiftui-and-combine/) . It helped me.

Comment: Okay I will check it out asap!! Thank uu

Answer (score 0):

The SwiftUI code isn't standard, we don't use view model objects that's what the View struct is for. `@StateObject` is for when you need a reference type in an `@State`. Also, in Combine's `ObservableObject` you are supposed to use `assign` instead of `sink`/`cancellable`. When async/await was added we can now use `.task(id:)` for networking instead of Combine.

Comment: Oh I had a typo in this example code (I forgot to add @Published for the selectionForSpiderman publisher) not it is working without a problem. However in my larger project it doesn't :( I think I must have there some typo otherwise it doesn't make any sense if this smaller version example works and the larger doesn't work 

Comment: Yes I learnt **Async/await** but still many companies wants me to know **Combine** mainly:( I thought about **.assign** however I want to sink just the [movies] and **.assign** just transforms it all. Btw thank u so much for your help!! ☺️